# How do various classes interact with each other in a PHP web application?

Tags: php, oop, symfony

I am new to OOP and i am learning symfony2.
This is my first experience with OOP.

Till now i have only created entity classes and CRUD controllers.

But i have not created my own classes.

Suppose i have class `User` , `ShoppingCart` and `Product`

```
Class User {
    $shoppingCart
}
```

---

```
Class Shoppingcart{
    $products
}
```

Now adding and removing product is ok

But i want to know what will happen if user click on product to add to cart.

i want to know which methods I need to create in order to add a product to the shopping cart and how the various classes should interact

Comment: can you elaborate on your question, at the moment it does not make much sense. Although i do feel that at its root you have a salient question to ask.

Comment: i am not able to edit my post. But i want to know that what happens behind the scenes when we click on add product to cart in object oriented way

Comment: you want to know what the method would look like to add an item to the cart?

Comment: If you're using symfony and these classes represent database entities they should be doctrine entities. In this case you can get doctrine to generate the methods for the interactions between these classes for you. You should typically have (on ShoppingCart) addProduct(Product $product), removeProduct(Product $product) and setProducts(array $products).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand this is **ONE** way of doing what you want to do in pure php

```
<?php   
class User {
     public $cart;
     public function __construct()
     {
        $this->cart = new Cart;
     }
}
class Cart {
   protected $products = array();
   public function __construct()
   {

   }
   public function addProduct(Product $product)
   {
       $this->products[] = $product;
   }
}
class Product
{
  //TODO DEFINE PRODUCT CLASS METHODS AND PROPERTIES
}
```

working with the objects on your addproduct.php page for example

```
<?php

//Include class files into the script
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "PATH/TO/CLASS/DIR/FROM/SERVER/ROOT";

//create $product object and set properties from form post

$user = new User();
$user->cart->addProduct($product);
```

****DISCLAIMER****
Ive not written php in a while and have typed this directly in the editor so their may be some syntax issues!

Comment: I've edited a couple of things, though this is not really how we do things in Symfony 2, as we try to avoid introducing implicit dependencies. But OP seems to be lost about OOP in general so this might help him.

Comment: thanks for that , i want to know when i click on add product then i need to make function in my controller lke addAction() and give the url for adding product

Comment: @user1504143 there are various ways of creating the addProduct method it depends how you want to send the information back to the server, you could do it in a AJAX call or in a tradiional postback.